# Recursion If/Else

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

When `recurse()` is called after the `if` statement, is there an implied `else{}` around it?

```
public static void recurse(int[] a, int position) {
      // BASE
      if (position == a.length){  return;}
      // RECURSIVE

      recurse(a, position + 1);

      System.out.println(a[position]);
}
```

Comment: It should be `reverse` and not `recurse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `else` is not implied.  An `else` case will only run when the `if` does **not** run.  In this case, since you return in the body of the `if`, the rest of the method is just skipped.  Logically they may be the same, but that's only because of the return.  If you removed that, the recursive call to `recurse` would run regardless of the condition in the `if` statement.

Comment: Assuming an array {1,2,3,4,5} and a call to the method with recurse(1), when 5 is finally called, how does it end up printing it? It calls 5 into the function, sees that position is equal to 5 and returns. How does it execute the print statement on the last call?

Comment: @user It doesn't execute the print on the last call.  When I run that method with an array of `{1,2,3,4,5}` like this: `recurse(a, 1);` It only prints out 5 4 3 2.

Comment: I defined the array starting at a[1], a[2].. a[5]

Answer (score 1):

see that the recurse function doesn't exist, you have to rename it to reverse, like this

```
public static void reverse(int[] a, int position) {
          // BASE
          if (position == a.length){  return;}
          // RECURSIVE

          reverse(a, position + 1);

          System.out.println(a[position]);
        }
```

And not, there is not an implicit else in the program ;)

Comment: Assuming an array {1,2,3,4,5} and a call to the method with recurse(1), when 5 is finally called, how does it end up printing it? It calls 5 into the function, sees that position is equal to 5 and returns. How does it execute the print statement on the last call?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing implied, but the `recurse()` call will only occur when the conditional in the if statement (`position == a.length`) evaluates to false (because of the `return` statement), so in this case it behaves the same.

Comment: Would it behave the same in all cases where an If statement returns? I believe it would..

Comment: Yes it would always behave the same as if the rest of the method had an `else` block around it.

Comment: Ok, when 5 is finally called, how does it end up printing it? It calls 5 into the function, sees that position is equal to 5 and returns. How does it execute the print statement on the last call?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. "else" means "only execute if the condition is false"

If the condition (position == a.length) is true, this function will return before "recurse" is called.

If that condition is false, the function will continue to call "recurse" and print.

Comment: It's just the stack un-winding part that bothers me a bit. The presence of an else statement just makes it appear to make more sense.